# How does .pth files distinguish between lines with path information and lines with Python code?

Tags: python, path, python-import, pth

It seems a .pth file can also mix *"folders to add to path"* information + also, some Python code, such as `import foo`. Example in `pywin32.pth`:

```
# .pth file for the PyWin32 extensions
win32
win32\lib
Pythonwin
# And some hackery to deal with environments where the post_install script
# isn't run.
import pywin32_bootstrap
```

**How does the .pth file parser distinguish lines for folders, and lines with Python code (import...)?** Here is seems ambiguous.

Note: Is there an official specification for the Python .pth file format? (I found some information on https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html but it's incomplete)

Note 2: it seems the .pth files can also include `zip` files instead of folders, see `python38._pth` in embedded Python:

```
python38.zip
.

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6abddd9f6afdddc09031989e0deb25e301ecf315/Lib/site.py#L29 (reformatted):

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form
> <package>.pth; its contents are additional directories (one per line)
> to be added to sys.path.
>
> Non-existing directories (or non-directories) are never added to
> sys.path; no directory is added to sys.path more than once.
>
> Blank lines and lines beginning with '#' are skipped. Lines starting
> with 'import' are executed.

The part that non-directories aren't added is obviously wrong/outdated. The code doesn't require a directory.